# flipping boolean value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Boolean` type field in my table (PostgreSQL 9.0)

Is there a way to write a query that update this field to the opposite value without knowing what is currently there?

if it's `True` then it will be updated to `False`.

if it's `False` then it will be updated to `True`.

Basically I'm asking if there is a mechanism that allows treating `Boolean` type same as `1 bit`. For example in C if `x` can be `{1,0}` you can simply write `x=!x` and if it was `0` it will be `1`, if it was `1` it will be `0`. No need for `IF` statment etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not to use operator NOT?

```
Update tableName
set c = NOT c 
where ...
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-logical.html

Example in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ddee/14)

Comment: It's a syntax error to table-qualify target columns in the `SET` clause. Must be: `SET c = NOT tablename.c`

Comment: @John, yes there was a syntax error in initial version of my answer, which was pointed out in comments. `set tableName.c = ` is not legal way. Even when `from` clause is present it is only possible to reference fields of table declared in `update` clause for changing values. So both works `set c = not tableName.c` and `set c = not c`. You can see sqlfiddle for a working solution and play with it to see options